# How do I reflect the changes I make to a list (present in another .py file) permanently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like after I open the .py file having the list, I should be able to see the items appended and/or inserted. So basically my final original copy of the list is changed. How do I do it?

Eg: I have a list_things in a list.py file.
     list_things = [john, albert, Martin, Suzzy]

I have a main.py file from where I will do changes to the list_things after I run in a GUI. This will only be temporary. If I stop it and re-run the file, It will again show me the old list contents (list_things) and not the updated list.

But I want the updated list to show in the GUI when I run it again.

Comment: That's the normal way adding to the list works. You'll need to post an example for us to see what is going wrong.

Comment: This question will likely be closed as too broad or unclear what you are asking. Cook up an example and if you are still puzzled, come on back.

Comment: I edited the question again. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Store it outside of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Python modules do not save data added to objects when the interpreter closes. Everything is reinitialized each time python runs. Generally, saving old data would be disastrous for a program.

But you can do it yourself. One of the easiest ways is to use the `pickle` module to save objects to files that you can read later. You have to worry about getting *and* saving, so people usually write helpers to do that for you, as in the example below.

But there is still a problem. If two copies of this program are running at the same time, one will overwrite the data of the other. Then you need something more complex, perhaps even a database such as sqlite.

```
import pickle

_list_things = None
_list_things_file = "./list_things.pkl"

def get_list_things():
    global _list_things
    try:
        _list_things = pickle.load(open(list_things_file, 'rb'))
    except OSError:
        _list_things = []
    return _list_things

def save_list_things():
    global _list_things
    assert _list_things is not None, "tried save before get"
    pickle.dump(open(_list_things_file, 'wb'))
```